# Library to display JS object in HTML in a way debuggers do

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am looking for efficient (means made by someone else) way to represent JS objects inside HTML page. Ideally I should provide arbitrary object and library should make dropdown or popup with all properties of that object that can be selected and viewed as well. Final goal is to make object representation as close to modern JS debugger interface as possible.

In case if I didn't get my point accross I want to find libarary that would allow to represent object on web page as on picture below.

[image: a busy cat]

So I would like to ask if any of you know a libarary that can help me to do this.

Update: I found that firebug-lite-debug.js has similar functionality but such approach requires unknown amount of work to extract code I need

Upadate: I ended up using json-formatter-js. It is able to render any js object and do it in lasy way so only expanded part of object is taken into account. Therefore gigantic things as window can be displayed.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but for earlier versions of nodejs there's an npm module called `node-inspector` which enables the process to be debugged using the Chrome debugger for client-side code. Note that this only works in Chrome. However, from about nodejs v6 onwards, this functionality is provided as part of nodejs.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have 2 candidates for autopsy (FIrebug and node-inspector). Will see how bloody it will be : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a pre-made widget that will display an object as HTML?

I'd probably start with something like [html-stringify](https://github.com/JedWatson/html-stringify)

It spits out a mostly clean HTML string with basic formatting. You could use that directly in your page, or add some additional styles to help match the style of your page. You can [try it out on RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/html-stringify) to see if it'll meet your needs.

(RunKit is a nice way to try out packages like this, so you can see what the output looks like without having to install them.)

Comment: Thank you! html-stringify on RunKit looks amazing and does what I need.